# Where are all of the barns located in Forza Horizon 5?

Tags: forza-horizon-5

I have just unlocked the 'Barn finds' feature but only one is showing on the map. How can I find the others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 14 Barn Finds in total throughout the whole map. In order to unlock them, you have two options:

- Complete different activities throughout the game to unlock them
- Purchase the 'Treasure Map' DLC which will unlock all except 1 of them (£2.50 in the UK on Steam)

It's personal preference but I bought the map as I don't have as much time to invest in the game as I would like. It is worth noting that just playing the game as intended and completing activities/objectives/story missions will eventually lead to you unlocking these anyway. Also worth noting is that the treasure map will *not* unlock those that require specific objectives to be completed as mentioned in the spoilers below.

I will list a number followed by a spoiler tag containing info on how to unlock that barn find. At the bottom of my answer will be a screenshot of all of the locations containing those numbers.

1. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
2. > Complete the Wilds Expedition objection '[Find the lost notes](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/forza-horizon-5-jungle-lost-notes-pilot-outfit-helmet-flight-recorder-rainy-day-fund-8041)'
3. > Complete the Apex Expedition objective '[Reach the top of the central ruin](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/forza-horizon-5-tulum-radio-beacon-jade-golden-statue-find-where-ramiro-landed-8041)'
4. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
5. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
6. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
7. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
8. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
9. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
10. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
11. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
12. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay
13. > Complete the Baja Expedition objective '[Hot spring lake sample](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/forza-horizon-5-volcano-thermal-suit-seismometer-hot-spring-lake-sample-8041)'
14. > This location unlocks randomly during gameplay

Screenshot of all barn locations:

> [image]