# Missing barn find

Tags: forza-horizon-5

So, I have been playing forza for a while and I have 14/15 barn finds. But i have been playing for hours and I haven't gotten the last barn find, is this a bug or is this supposed to happen

Comment: this might be a difficult ask, but could you share a screenshot of your map with only barn finds showing? that will help us cross reference and determine which one is missing.

Comment: I believe this can be answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392943/where-are-all-of-the-barns-located-in-forza-horizon-5)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard for me to tell precisely which one you're missing, but I'm near certain it's the barn find you get for buying the **La Cabaña** house on the western side of the map. As far as I know, it's the only one that doesn't open automatically.

The house is only 150,000 credits so you should be able to afford it easily.

Comment: i did say 14/15 of which its actualy 13/14 but the house worked anyways thanks

Comment: If this answer helped you, please be sure to mark it as “accepted”